Table not being created with schema
Im working on a project where I have to create 2 connections, one to h2 one to s3 to upload files. The s3 is up & running & the schema is creating just fine, although when trying to do the same with h2, the table is not being created so I'm getting an error when cron is checking if there are any files in "PENDING" status to be uploaded to db.
For the s3 I'm using postgres, & the schema in that language is working just fine. Issue is with the h2.
Im running the app -> 3 dots on 3op right of InteliJ -> Edit -> Active profiles -> type in: local
 Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Tabela "FILE_IMPORT" does not exist.
Table "FILE_IMPORT" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT id FROM file_import WHERE status = ? ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 1 [42102-214] 

Application-local.yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test
    username: sa
    password:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update  # or your preferred value
    open-in-view: false
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true  # This line enables the H2 console for development
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 5000MB
      max-request-size: 5000MB
  upload:
    dir: "src/main/resources/files-to-import"
  integration:
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always
server:
  port: 8080
file-storage:
  solution: local

logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        SQL: DEBUG


schema-h2.sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.file_import (
                                                  id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                                                  created_at TIMESTAMP(6),
    file_path VARCHAR(255),
    finished_at TIMESTAMP(6),
    last_processed_row BIGINT,
    started_at TIMESTAMP(6),
    status VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT file_import_status_check CHECK (status IN ('PENDING', 'SUCCESS', 'FAILED'))
    );

LocalFileStorage

package com.example.personmanagement.file;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;


@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "file-storage", name = "solution", havingValue = "local")
public class LocalFileStorage implements FileStorage {

    @Value("${spring.upload.dir}")
    private String UPLOAD_DIR;

    @Override
    public String save(InputStream inputsStream, String originalFilename, long byteSize) throws IOException {
        String uniqueFilename = System.currentTimeMillis() + "_" + originalFilename;
        Path filePath = Path.of(UPLOAD_DIR, uniqueFilename);
        Files.copy(inputsStream, filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        return uniqueFilename;
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader load(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Path filePath = Path.of(UPLOAD_DIR, fileName);
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(String.valueOf(filePath))));
    }

}

Methods where the code is being run with the cron & it sees that there is no table

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
@Slf4j
public class FileImportRepository {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public FileImportRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void insert(FileImport fileImport) throws DataAccessException {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO file_import (file_path, last_processed_row, status, created_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, fileImport.getFilePath(), fileImport.getLastProcessedRow(),
                fileImport.getStatus().toString(), fileImport.getCreatedAt());
    }

    public void update(FileImport fileImport) throws DataAccessException {
        String sql = """
                UPDATE file_import
                SET
                    file_path = ?,
                    last_processed_row = ?,
                    status = ?,
                    finished_at = ?,
                    started_at = ?
                WHERE id = ?
                """;
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, fileImport.getFilePath(), fileImport.getLastProcessedRow(),
                fileImport.getStatus().toString(), fileImport.getFinishedAt(), fileImport.getStartedAt(), fileImport.getId());
    }

    public Optional<Long> findFirstByStatusOrderByCreatedAtAsc() throws EmptyResultDataAccessException {
        String sql = "SELECT id FROM file_import WHERE status = ? ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 1";
        Long fileId = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{FileStatus.PENDING.toString()}, Long.class);
        return Optional.ofNullable(fileId);
    }

    public Optional<FileImport> findById(Long id) throws DataAccessException {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM file_import WHERE id = ?";
        FileImport fileImport = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{id}, new FileImportRowMapper());
        return Optional.ofNullable(fileImport);
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        String sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE file_import";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
    }
}

Could you possibly help me out with creating the table? Im unable to connect to the h2 console, as the login part is from Spring boot rather than h2.
Changing the schema
changing the profile

Can you try these two ways:

rename schema-h2.sql to schema.sql (check now)
Use the schema.sql file name and remove "public" from the DDL.

    From 
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.file_import
    To 
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS file_import


Seems that it has helped, although my intention was to use different schema for different databases. Altough at the moment I have to use the "schema.sql" name for it to work.
